# Changing An Elements Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I would like to change the content of a element with a button click and then have it return back to its original message. How Would i do this preferable with toggle class if possible.

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Day Practice</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> HotDogs</h1>
<input type=button id=button value=button>
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){ 
$("h1").html("Change to this");
});


</script>
```

This changes the header with a button, but I don't know how to revert it when I click on the button again. Maybe Toggle Class, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should solve:

```
$( "#button" ).toggle(function() {
  $("h1").html("Change here");
}, function() {
  $("h1").html("Revert back here");
});
```

Comment: didn't work when i ran the page immediately the button disappears

Comment: can you try something else i like the simplicity of your code though, maybe something different

Comment: @SamOpoku Why do you accept an answer that didn't work for you? I mean, the reason it doesn't work is because `toggle()` sets an element visible / invisable and therefor this is a bad answer anyway, but still..

Comment: Ahem.. Quote "jQuery .toggle: Description: Display or hide the matched elements.". http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Ahem... Are you blind? He posted a JSFiddle that proves it works in his last comment. And btw, you've got the wrong toggle: "Description: Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks." https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: I stand corrected for that. But jQuery having 2 functions with the exact same name.. no wonder that causes confusion

Comment: @mbinette Seems the event `.toggle()` is deprecated: Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to toggle and check, and store the old text whenever you change it. An example:

```
var flag = false;
var old_text = "";

$("#button").click(function () {
    if (flag) {
        $("h1").html(old_text);
    } else {
        old_text = $("h1").html();
        $("h1").html("Change to this");
    }
    flag = !flag;    
});
```

Comment: This worked but could you possible do a more simplified version of this

Comment: how simplified do you want it? It's quite a small code block. I'll have a think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var alternate_text = "Change to this";
$("#button").click(function(){ 
    var temp = $("h1").html()
    $("h1").html(alternate_text);
    alternate_text = temp; // Switch the two instances of text.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you prefered to do this with `toggleClass()`, here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var oldContent;

    $("#button").click(function(){
        if($(".newCont")[0]){
            $("h1").html(oldContent);
        } else {
            oldContent = $("h1").html();
            $("h1").html("New text here");
        }

        $("h1").toggleClass("newCont");
    });
});
```